# Raise Events Custom Control Class which Inherits Base Class

Tags: vb.net, class, base-class, raiseevent, axshockwaveflash

I'm trying to design a "pass-through" for the axShockwaveFlash control. This control does not have `.MouseDown`, `.MouseUp` or `.MouseMove` events associated with it. Sadly, I need to detect these events on any shockwave controls as they are used in another class (which detects these events on a variety of different controls).

So, I tried designing a custom class, modifying the axShockwaveFlash class to include these events. However, I get the following error:

"Derived classes cannot raise base class events."

on the line:

```
RaiseEvent MouseDown(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Full code (minus the up and move functions):

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading

Public Class MousedFlash

    Inherits AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash

    'WndProc Inputs:
    Private Const WM_RBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H204
    Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H201

    Protected Overloads Sub OnMouseDown()
        RaiseEvent MouseDown(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_RBUTTONDOWN
                Debug.WriteLine("MOUSE FLASH - right down!")
                Call OnMouseDown()
                Return
            Case WM_LBUTTONDOWN
                Debug.WriteLine("MOUSE FLASH - left down!")
                Call OnMouseDown()
                Return
        End Select
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I think the Base Class is `AxShockwaveFlashObjects` - but I can't see the mouse events defined in here. Bit out my depth on this one - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. In the end a mixture of carelessness on my part and the wrong type of over-ride. Final working replacement:

```
Shadows Event MouseDown As System.EventHandler
Protected Overridable Sub OnMouseDownTrigger()
    RaiseEvent MouseDown(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

Comment: Be careful with that. Marking something as `Shadows` is rarely the correct thing to do.  I'n my 10 years or so of .NET experience, I think I've used it maybe twice.  Be sure you understand exactly what it does by reading this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4swkw24.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Having a look at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx) it looks like instead of trying to raise the base class event, you should call the Sub which handles that event directly. So try replacing

```
Protected Overloads Sub OnMouseDown()
    RaiseEvent MouseDown(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

with

```
Protected Overloads Sub OnMouseDown()
    MyBase.MouseDown(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```